# Messenger ID Matching API returns empty data

Tags: facebook, messenger

I want to get the real facebook id of users that interact with my messenger app using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/connecting-accounts). When I debug using the graph api explorer I get results if I use my own psid returned by messenger to send a request but if I use the psid of other users it gives me an empty array of data. What may be the cause of the problem?

**GET /{my-own-psid}/ids_for_apps** - returns a result

**GET /{other-users-psid}/ids_for_apps** - doesn't give a result

Comment: Has your app been submitted for review? Is the user a tester/admin of your app?

Comment: Thanks for dropping by. The app is still in local development and not yet submitted for review and yes, the user that is failing is a tester.

Comment: Has the other user registered with or used your app?

Comment: @che-azeh Yes, he is registered through Facebook Login on my site.